# 2 variables next to eachother

Tags: php

I want to input fields for first name and last name, but I also want them to be displayed together, but I can't quite figure out yet how to make the 2 name variables next to eachother!
Here's the code I have for this:

```
$first_name = $poster_data['first_name'];

$last_name = $poster_data['last_name'];

$name = $first_name, $last_name;
```

Thanks!

Comment: all the answers are almost identical. I can't choose which one to upvote

Comment: Jasir helped me most, no need for spaces I just put that in and it worked

Comment: So in my search I found this exact duplicate except it got -17 downvotes and closed. :D http://stackoverflow.com/q/10600946/995876 Why are you special?

Comment: I didnt know this was called string concentration, how am I supposed to search something I obviously dont know. . .

Comment: If you're working with names, you should also read Patrick McKenzie's "[Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)" - be careful about assuming that everyone's name is the kind of name you're familiar with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$name = "{$first_name}, {$last_name}";
```

Comment: @checkit923 Please understand that this is but one way to do string concatenation (and this technique is not always the correct one to use in every circumstance).

Comment: This should be using a string concatenation as SpikeX said this way of doing it can be problematic later on.

Answer (score 5):

To combine strings you use the concatenation operator: `.`.

```
$name = $first_name . $last_name;
```

Though you probably want a space between them:

```
$name = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$name = $first_name." ". $last_name;
```

The extra `" "` is for a space between the two.

Answer (score 2):

```
$name = $first_name.', '.$last_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's called **string concatenation**, and in PHP it's expressed like so, with the `.` operator:

```
$name = $first_name . $last_name;
```

This will print "`JohnDoe`". If you want to add a space:

```
$name = $first_name . " " . $last_name;
```

This will print "`John Doe`".

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $firstname . " " . $lastname
```

to display the name as John Smith